# how to get only the english character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import string
import json,threading 

def cleanInput(input):
    input=re.sub(' +'," ",input)
    input=re.sub('\[[0-9]*\]',"",input)
    input=re.sub('\n+'," ",input)
    input=bytes(input,'UTF-8')
    input=input.decode('ascii','ignore')
    cleanInput=[]
    print(input)
    input=input.split(" ")
    for i in input:
        i.strip(string.punctuation)
        if len(i)>1 or (i.lower()=='a' or i.lower()=='i'):
            cleanInput.append(i)
    return cleanInput
```

The problem i am having  is that at`input=input.split(" ")` it gives the following error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`,so 
i printed and it looks like a normal text with no brackets(i.e [ ]),
i tried it on different large texts it gives the same error
How can i fix so i get only English words, 'i','a' with no other whatever language characters or symbols or `\n` .

Comment: can you share the link of input you are giving.

Comment: soup.find().get_text  from site with large texts